How to Configure AWS ACM SSL Certificates with URL Validation for EKS Cluster Using AWS CDK Python
I'm currently setting up an Amazon EKS cluster using AWS CDK in Python and require assistance with configuring SSL certificates through AWS Certificate Manager (ACM). My goal is to secure my services with HTTPS, specifically focusing on URL validation for the certificate issuance process using a public domain name.
Here's what I've done so far:

Created an EKS cluster with a specific VPC, subnets, and IAM roles.
Set up a Node Group within the EKS cluster.
Deployed Kong as an Ingress Controller and Cert-Manager using Helm charts.
Configured AWS Private CA Issuer for certificate management.

However, I'm facing challenges in integrating ACM for SSL certificate management, particularly with the URL validation step required for issuing certificates. I understand that ACM supports DNS validation, but I'm unsure how to integrate this process with my EKS setup, especially considering the dynamic nature of Kubernetes resources. I don't want to use AWS Private CA since I already have a public domain in my Route53.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to achieve the following with AWS CDK Python?

Step 1: Request an ACM certificate for my public domain.
Step 2: Perform URL validation for the certificate request.
Step 3: Ensure the certificate is issued, integrated and available for use with my EKS Kong ingress resources.
Step 4: Any other necessary actions with ALB or other resources.

Any examples or best practices on how to automate this process within the AWS CDK Python framework would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the part of code I used to create my cluster,
        # EKS Cluster setup
        cluster = eks.Cluster(
            scope=self,
            id='EksCluster',
            vpc=vpc,
            cluster_name='eks-cluster',
            default_capacity=0,
            version=eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_28,
            kubectl_layer=KubectlV28Layer(self, "KubectlLayer"),
            vpc_subnets=[ec2.SubnetSelection(subnets=private_subnets)],
            role=cluster_role,
            cluster_logging=[eks.ClusterLoggingTypes.API, eks.ClusterLoggingTypes.AUTHENTICATOR],
            masters_role=cluster_admin,
            security_group = cluster_security_group,
            tags=common_tags_dict
        )

        # NodePool
        managed_node_group = eks.Nodegroup(
            scope=self, 
            id="ManagedNodeGroup",
            cluster=cluster,  
            nodegroup_name="eks-ng",
            instance_types=[
                ec2.InstanceType("m5.large")
            ],
            desired_size=1,
            max_size=2,
            min_size=1,
            subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnets=private_subnets),
            ami_type=eks.NodegroupAmiType.AL2_X86_64,
            node_role=nodegroup_role,
            tags=common_tags_dict
        )

        # Create Kube Namespace for Kong
        kong_namespace = eks.KubernetesManifest(
            scope=self, 
            id="KongNamespace",
            cluster=cluster,
            manifest=[{
                "apiVersion": "v1",
                "kind": "Namespace",
                "metadata": {
                    "name": "kong"
                }
            }]
        )

        # Deploy Kong Ingress Controller using Helm
        kong_chart = eks.HelmChart(
            scope=self, 
            id= "KongIngressController",
            cluster=cluster,
            chart="kong",
            repository="https://charts.konghq.com",
            namespace="kong",
            release="kong",
            values={
                "ingressController": {
                    "enabled": True
                }
            }
        )

        # Deploy Cert Manager using Helm
        cert_manager_chart = eks.HelmChart(
            scope=self,
            id="CertManager",
            cluster=cluster,
            chart="cert-manager",
            repository="https://charts.jetstack.io",
            namespace="cert-manager",
            release="cert-manager",
            values={
                "installCRDs": True,
                "nodeSelector": {
                    "kubernetes.io/os": "linux"
                },
                "tolerations": [
                    {
                        "key": "node-role.kubernetes.io/master",
                        "operator": "Exists",
                        "effect": "NoSchedule"
                    }
                ]
            }
        )

        # Deploy AWS Private CA Issuer using Helm
        private_ca_issuer_chart = eks.HelmChart(
            scope=self,
            id="PrivateCAIssuer",
            cluster=cluster,
            chart="aws-privateca-issuer",
            repository="https://cert-manager.github.io/aws-privateca-issuer",
            namespace="cert-manager",
            release="aws-privateca-issuer",
            values={
                "clusterName": cluster.cluster_name,
                "region": self.region,
                "serviceAccount": {
                    "create": True,
                    "name": "aws-privateca-issuer"
                }
            }
        )

Thank you ツ
